# Include UIImagePickerController in a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to make a view that works like pages[image: works like pages], with a popup in which I can choose to pick a photo from my library or create a new one.

Currently, I have a ViewController, present as Popover. In the ViewController, I inserted a ContainerView and I declared that its class is UIImageViewController. This is showing me the photo library but I don't find how to pick anything in : [My ViewController presented as Popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wMF9.png).

When I choose a photo, nothing's happening. I've tried to put some functions

```
 (func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!))
```

in my ViewController but it does not work. I've read that UIImagePickerController does not support subclassing, so how Pages do this stuff ?

Here is my ViewController code :

```
import UIKit

class MenuAddResources: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var newMedia: Bool?
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
            if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            //load the camera interface
            let picker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.newMedia = true
        }
        else{
            //no camera available
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ERROR", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("NO_CAMERA", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction)in
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        if error != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ERROR", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("IMAGE_SAVE_FAILED", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        })

        // Let's store the image
        let now:Int = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 85)
        //imageData?.writeToFile(documentsDirectory + "/\(now).jpg", atomically: true)
        print(imageData)

        /* will do stuff with the image */
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: please share relevant code also

Comment: I've edited. Something very strange is if I do not put the line "let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()", the picker is not showed...

Comment: _When I choose a photo, nothing's happening. I've tried to put some functions_ . so you mean to say UIImagePicker comes but you cant pick any photo from it ?

Comment: Exactly. If I use the button to take a picture, the print shows well the imageData variable. However when I choose a photo from the library, the picker disappears and it doesn't print anything, imageData is empty...

Comment: do you know how to use breakpoints ?

Comment: I know how to add/remove breakpoints but not really what to do with it after :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears you are using UIImagePickerViewController through a
>   container view and therefore the delegate isnt set , thus no callbacks
>   to receiving the image picked methods.

To fix this, you must override `prepareForSegue` in your class
and in that cast the `segue.destinationViewController` to your picker and set its `delegate` to `self`